# How to resolve Quarkus Hibernate insert SQLGrammerException

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus

My configuration is the same as the `Quarkus guide`.  I can now query from my database, but trying to `insert` produces this `exception`.  I am VERY experienced in JPA using Eclipselink, so I know my Entity class is not the problem, as I can query the database with it using a standard JPQL syntax.
The insert fails on a simple `em.persist(entity)`.

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Unsupported Types value: 1,426,407,511
```

My pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

My Entity code:

```
package com.lmco.is3.nc.micro.datasvc.jpa.entity;

import com.lmco.is3.data.uci.NotificationSeverityType;
import com.lmco.is3.data.uci.NotificationStateType;
import com.lmco.is3.nc.micro.datasvc.jpa.converter.PostgresUuidConverter;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Convert;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "ALERT_NOTIFICATION")
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class AlertNotificationEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Convert(converter = PostgresUuidConverter.class)
    @Column(name = "ALERT_NOTIFICATION_UID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private UUID alertNotificationUid;

    public UUID getAlertNotificationUid() {
        return alertNotificationUid;
    }

    public void setAlertNotificationUid(UUID alertNotificationUid) {
        this.alertNotificationUid = alertNotificationUid;
    }

    @Convert(converter = PostgresUuidConverter.class)
    @Column(name = "SUBJECT_UID")
    private UUID subjectUid;

    public UUID getSubjectUid() {
        return subjectUid;
    }

    public void setSubjectUid(UUID subjectUid) {
        this.subjectUid = subjectUid;
    }

    /*
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "ALERT_NOTIF_ENTITY_PERSPECTIVE",
                     joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ALERT_NOTIFICATION_UID", referencedColumnName = "ALERT_NOTIFICATION_UID"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    @OrderColumn
    @Column(name = "ENTITY_PERSPECTIVE_TYPE")
    private List<EntityPerspectiveType> entityPerspectiveTypes;

    public List<EntityPerspectiveType> getEntityPerspectiveTypes() {
        return entityPerspectiveTypes;
    }

    public void setEntityPerspectiveTypes(List<EntityPerspectiveType> entityPerspectiveTypes) {
        this.entityPerspectiveTypes = entityPerspectiveTypes;
    }
     */

    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    @Column(name = "NOTIFICATION_STATE")
    private NotificationStateType state;

    public NotificationStateType getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(NotificationStateType state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    @Column(name = "NOTIFICATION_SEVERITY")
    private NotificationSeverityType severity;

    public NotificationSeverityType getSeverity() {
        return severity;
    }

    public void setSeverity(NotificationSeverityType severity) {
        this.severity = severity;
    }

    @Column(name = "NOTIFICATION_TIME")
    private double notificationTime;

    public double getNotificationTime() {
        return notificationTime;
    }

    public void setNotificationTime(double notificationTime) {
        this.notificationTime = notificationTime;
    }

    @Convert(converter = PostgresUuidConverter.class)
    @Column(name = "SYSTEM_UID")
    private UUID systemUid;

    public UUID getSystemUid() {
        return systemUid;
    }

    public void setSystemUid(UUID systemUid) {
        this.systemUid = systemUid;
    }

    /*
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "ALERT_NOTIF_APPLIES_TO_ENTITY",
                     joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ALERT_NOTIFICATION_UID", referencedColumnName = "ALERT_NOTIFICATION_UID"))
    @Convert(converter = PostgresUuidConverter.class)
    @OrderColumn
    @Column(name = "APPLIES_TO_ENTITY_UID")
    private List<UUID> appliesToEntityUids;

    public List<UUID> getAppliesToEntityUids() {
        return appliesToEntityUids;
    }

    public void setAppliesToEntityUids(List<UUID> appliesToEntityUids) {
        this.appliesToEntityUids = appliesToEntityUids;
    }
     */

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        AlertNotificationEntity that = (AlertNotificationEntity) o;
        return Objects.equals(alertNotificationUid, that.alertNotificationUid);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(alertNotificationUid);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your entity and your insertion code ?

Comment: The entity class is the same as what I am using from Eclipselink (which I would MUCH prefer using over Hibernate!) and I have even commented out child tables and it makes no difference.  And my "insertion code", is nothing more that "em.persist(entity)"

Comment: So it seems the problem is with the PostgresUuidConverter.class.  I used an Entity class that did not depend on that, and the insert worked fine.  So I will be digging further into that as the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I resolved my own problem, simpler than I expected.
I changed my usage of PostresUuidConverter to `@Type(type = "pg-uuid")` and all works now.